# what does it mean to run a time series model in levels?

Tags: time-series, terminology, vector-autoregression

I have seen the phrases ***running a var in levels*** and ***running a var in difference*** very frequently, either on this site or elsewhere.

I understand running a var in difference basically means to difference the var model ($I(d)$) and write it in $I(0)$ form.

but I failed to find a relevant definition for levels, and the usage of levels in the phrase was unclear to me as to what kind of transformation it is indicating.

What does it mean to run a var in levels please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VAR in levels just means without taking any differences of the data. If your data in levels (i.e. as-is without any differencing) is $I(d)$, then first-differencing will make your data  $I(d-1)$, and thus differencing $d$ times will make the data $I(0)$. Often times we estimate VAR in differences to make the data $I(0)$, so that we can work with stationary data. The appropriate specification, if your data are $I(1)$, will depend heavily on whether the  series are cointegrated.

Comment: thanks very much, now I understand!